# How to expand available Tags or Sub-tags Related tags?

Tags: discussion

I want to make sure I am in the right "Stack" so to speak.

My daughter has two "baby-daddies" who 
over the last two years have both chosen to disobey their Child Support orders and move out of State. In an effort to help my daughter, I have several questions I would like to research here and perhaps ask this group, as long as this is the right "Stack".  If not here, what stack would be more appropriate?

Also, I am wondering if there are more granular Tags that I can search for or use to better categorize my questions and any responses I might be fortunate enough to receive.  Or, how do you create new Tags for this purpose?

Comment: I just flagged this because it’s not a question about parenting, but about the scope of this site: It should go to our [meta] site instead of here on [main]. For a start, please browse our [help], which gives you some pointers and check whether we have similar questions over on [meta]. Off the cuff, I can say that everything about *legal matters* should probably go to Law SE (check their help center about scope and rules, too). If want to ask about *parenting*, this is the right place - including grandparents, family members and friends in a “parent-like” situation.

Comment: First time here, and thanks to Stephie, it will be my last. Your comments where not helpful, mostly critical and it was clear you have no compassion for a grand parents plight of this type.  You had no way of knowing what types of followup questions I planned to ask of this group, but chose to assume I would not or could not stay on topic. Your brand of impatience and "Hall monitor" like criticism only insured I have the worst possible first time user experience. You sure told me now diddn't you. I get it, I am not welcome.

Comment: I’m sorry if there was a miscommunication, I truly meant to help. You explicitly asked for “the right Stack“ and both Parenting Meta and the Help Center are the best places for finding that. Likewise for how to use tags effectively. If the verb „flagging“ irritates you, that is not a way to criticize, but especially in your case simply a mechanism to call a moderator for support: they can move your post if they agree with the suggestion. I always thought that the smaller SE sites like this one were especially welcoming. If I didn’t say „Welcome!“, it’s because I ran out to space.

Comment: So let me do that now: Welcome to Parenting SE!

Comment: Grampa - to follow on from Stephie's comment, Stack Exchange is very strict - the help centre lists those topics that are welcome here. And while we are compassionate to all folks, that is irrelevant to the SE requirement for standalone answerable questions that can be answered practically.

Comment: @GrampaBill I don't understand. Stephie was helping you go to the correct place to ensure you get proper answers. She was kind, and not at all impatient or like a "hall monitor". I can tell you are very sensitive about this issue, so maybe that's where the problem arose? Each question is self contained, so follow-up questions are not allowed, except when made their own separate question. Our goal is to make every question a good one, which is what stephie was kindly and politely helping you do.

Answer (score 2):

This will depend entirely on the questions you ask. Please read the [help pages](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help), not just because they list types of questions that work here, but also  help to explain how Stack Exchange works, as it is very different from an online discussion forum.

> We welcome questions on topics like these:
>
> - matters of upbringing,
> - safety considerations,
> - food and feeding,
> - health and hygiene,
> - development and growth,
> - language development,
> - behavior and social skills,
> - discipline and punishment,
> - childrens'/family games for developmental purposes or parental sanity.
>
> Some subjects might be on-topic here but you can get better response on our sister sites,
>   for instance:
>
> - Scientific questions about child psychology (see the developmental-psychology tag on Cognitive Sciences SE)
> - sports and fitness (see fitness.SE),
> - computer games, educational software, other IT questions (see superuser),
> - family finances (see money.SE).
>
> And some subjects are considered off-topic because they're not directly related to parenting,
>   for instance:
>
> - specific medical issues (we're not doctors!),
> - legal issues (too localized),
> - shopping recommendations (too localized, and not timeless),
> - relationships,
> - sex,
> - generic and universal questions that are lazily worded "... for kids".
>
> Please note that opinions shared here should be backed up either with a reference, or experiences that happened to you personally. Also, posts that primarily exist to push a specific agenda (propaganda), and soap-boxing, are not welcome.

Legal questions are off topic here, but **may** be on topic on Law.SE.

Tags are only created as they are needed - generally this is quite a rare occurrence now, as this is a well-established site and many tags were created in our early days.